# How to obtain Data from local retail stores?

Tags: geolocation, repository, information-retrieval

I am looking for basically a repository of information regarding stores. Say I have an app, how would I find all the local stores that sell 'cellphones'? I have been using Google search to solve this but no luck. I know this is possible because through the use of Google maps or i-maps, you are able to find stores and public locations near you. I want to be able to find the store Items of a store. So i could for example say in my search in-app, "What stores will be selling PS4?".  This will then display the location of all stores who will be selling PS4. I am not looking for code, I'm looking for data where this would be stored, like Data.gov etc...

Edit* 
That's what I believed (@Naomi Owens), in regards to the item stock of a store. So since not knowing the stores current Item stock information, a go around would be to find all the stores that would seemingly sell that particular item and then based off assumptions and factual information regarding the release date of 'said item', notify the user that the queried item will be sold at those retailers based off assumptions. I guess you could then use a percentage system based off of 'logical assumption' the likelihood of a store selling that item. Example Walmart would have a higher likelihood (percentage) of selling a PS4 than would Fye (or some other smaller electronic store).

Answer (score 0):

Locating nearby stores selling a particular product should be simple enough using Google API. The stock in these shops is constantly changing however and if such a database existed may not be very accurate. Each shop's stock, orders, customers etc. are located on their own private database which you wont have access to for obvious reasons. Many apps that do this type of thing do so through html scraping or xml parsing rss feeds. Neither of those would work in this case given that most shops do not use rss feeds and the large amount of html scraping that would be required otherwise.

Edit -  I doubt that a database exists containing a list of all of a stores assumed stock, since the majority of people are only interested in live information. Sounds like a database that you would have to create yourself or pay someone else to create for you.